# Sass Ruby transition filter effect error message

Tags: css, ruby, sass, css-transitions, compass-sass

The following css transition effects are not compiling in Sass and, I am receiving the following error message.

```
Line 10 of _brightness.scss: $color: 100% is not a color for `red'
```

This was working on my site, but I think update of Sass has broken my effects and made it return the error above. The following is my transition with a hover effect, which does not work.

```
.viewimage img {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;   
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.viewimage:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(80%);
}
```

Does anyone know why this error is occurring and what an appropriate fix for it would be?

Comment: This will maybe be helpfull: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1418

Comment: thanks Nico O, gave me the right direction for fixing the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to 'Nico O' for suggesting the link, have found the fix using the following code.

```
.viewimage img {
  @include filter(#{"brightness(1)"});
  @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in-out);
}

.viewimage:hover img {
  @include filter(#{"brightness(0.8)"})
}
```